# Custom list component, similar to TListBox

Tags: delphi, listbox, custom-component

I am currently looking for an object similar to `TListBox` that will display a list of other objects. I'm finding it really hard to explain so here's a picture of the sort of thing I'm looking for: [image]

Each item needs to be able to display multiple lines of variable text, display images, be *clickable*, be able to host buttons on it.

Is there an object like this already? If not, how would I create one?

Comment: you can implement custom paint -> http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomListBox.OnDrawItem or build your own component

Comment: See [`this example`](http://www.lischke-online.de/images/stories/screen-shots/Helium2.gif) of using [`Virtual TreeView`](http://www.lischke-online.de/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview).

Comment: You can create your own component using the TCollection and TCollectionItem classes. Google those - here is a starter link - http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc083101d.htm

Comment: Don't think in terms of "hosting controls": such solutions do not scale. You want a custom-drown list that emulates the buttons. Once you know your "target" you can start coding and ask specific questions if necessary. As LU RD suggests, Virtual TreeView is a good base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming that you want to do this in Windows, then any XE version of Delphi has the TCategoryPanelGroup control which is pretty much what you appear to be asking for.

Comment: Delphi 2009 also has a control named `TCategoryPanelGroup`. Is it the same?

Comment: Thanks exactly what i was looking for. Do you know how to get rid of the header fer each panel?

Comment: To remove the header, set the property HeaderHeight of CategoryPanelGroup to 0